# How to change teamsite text layout programmatically?

Tags: sharepoint

I have a code that creates a teamsite. After that I add some web parts to wiki web part zone(rich content area). In SharePoint 2010 user can change a text layout of the rich content in page edit mode.

Is there any way to programmatically change the text layout of the rich text area? I would want to set "two columns with header"-layout after site creation has completed.

My site is created like this.

```
site = elevatedSite.SelfServiceCreateSite(params.....);
rootWeb = site.RootWeb;
rootWeb.ApplyWebTemplate("STS#0");
SPListItem currentItem = rootWeb.Item;
var xhtml = currentItem[SPBuiltInFieldId.WikiField] as string;
```

Now I can modify the xhtml string and save it back to the page. I have tried to change it so that it contains exatly the same html structure which have created by sharepoint itself, when changing the text layout. After that change, actually it is not recognized as "two columns with header"-layout in sharepoint. It is still default one-column layout. Is there anybody who knows is it possible to change the text layout of the rich text area programmatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found answer from here http://donalconlon.wordpress.com/2010/05/04/sp2010-creating-a-wiki-page-using-the-om/. SharePoint stores the information about used layout to the hidden span-element in wiki page.

For example, this presents two column layout without the header or footer.

```
<span id="layoutsData" style="display: none">false,false,2</span>
```

first **false** = no header
second **false** = no footer
**2** = two columns

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for some information on doing the same thing.  I found this blog post that checks out the page, edits the content then publish and approves it.

[SharePoint 2010 change page content data through Object Model / API – Console Application](http://rburgundy.wordpress.com/2010/04/20/sharepoint-2010-change-page-content-data-through-object-model-api-%E2%80%93-console-application/)

Answer (score 0):

If you need to modify pure HTML content, its better to use cutom IHttpHandler (wrapped in dll) and connect it to SharePoint via web.config. Is is also allowing to modify dynamic content like AJAX responses.